# awk confuses two distinct strings that contain numbers

Tags: string, awk, comparison

I use the awk script

```
 BEGIN { 
   FS=";";
   id=0; 
 }

 NR >= 1 {
  if($2 == id) {
    print "Old person", $2, id;
  } else {
    id = $2;
    print "New person ", id
  }
}
```

on the following file

```
1220100120160850207;12201001201608502;114.384332;59475;16
1220100120160850208;12201001201608502;114.384332;59475;16
1220100120160850301;12201001201608503;68.3642617;59475;07
1220100120160850302;12201001201608503;68.3642617;59475;17
1220100120160850401;12201001201608504;68.3642617;59475;08
1220100120160850402;12201001201608504;68.3642617;59475;11
1220100120160850403;12201001201608504;68.3642617;59475;13
1220100120160850404;12201001201608504;68.3642617;59475;16
```

and obtain

```
New person  12201001201608502 114.384332 
Old person 12201001201608502 12201001201608502
New person  12201001201608503 68.3642617 
Old person 12201001201608503 12201001201608503
Old person 12201001201608504 12201001201608503
Old person 12201001201608504 12201001201608503
Old person 12201001201608504 12201001201608503
Old person 12201001201608504 12201001201608503
```

which is wrong since it does not detect that person `12201001201608504` is new!
Any explanation?

Comment: whats expected output

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is related to how `awk` converts strings to numbers, but I don't immediately see the significance of the value where the break occurs.  I was able to reproduce the problem on a Mac using both the Apple version of Awk and GNU Awk (4.1.3 tested).

It's possible to fix the problem by forcing string comparisons instead of numeric comparison, like this:

```
BEGIN { FS=";"; id=0; }

{
  if ($2 == id "") {.    # Probably important
    print "Old person", $2, id;
  } else {
    id = $2 "";          # Possibly important
    COEQ = $3;
    print "New person", id, COEQ
  }
}
```

On your data file, that produces:

```
New person 12201001201608502 114.384332 
Old person 12201001201608502 12201001201608502
New person 12201001201608503 68.3642617 
Old person 12201001201608503 12201001201608503
New person 12201001201608504 68.3642617 
Old person 12201001201608504 12201001201608504
Old person 12201001201608504 12201001201608504
Old person 12201001201608504 12201001201608504
```

I've removed various extraneous parts of the script.  I'm not convinced that `COEQ` should be used, though no big harm done.

Comment: `id=0` initialization is not necessary and forcing the variable to be numeric.  However, removing is not going to fix it but you only need the stringification at the assignment.  This is a **gotcha** in `awk`.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't experiment with which of the two 'convert to string by appending an empty string' was necessary — with both, it worked; either seems to be adequate (at least if `id = 0` is omitted) .  Not initializing `id` is also a simple improvement (and using `-F';'` on the command line then eliminates the `BEGIN` block).  I think that the key points remain "Awk is flexible about treating strings as numbers and vice versa", and "the comparison fails because the values are converted to numbers and this loses information when the numbers have too many digits".

Comment: if you don't use `$2"" == id` and don't init `id` in the BEGIN section then the first comparison is strnum-vs-unassigned (a variation of numeric-string type) which is still numeric so though it'll probably do what you want with the given input values, IMHO it's at least clearer if not more accurate to force a string comparison and once you do that then you don't need to cast $2 to string in the `id=$2""` assignment.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, worked fine for me. I was indeed suspecting a conversion to integer for the comparison but didn't find how to force string comparison. Thanks again !

Comment: To be clear, the problem IS a conversion to number as @JonathanLeffler mentions, but it isn't a conversion to integer as MoezK mentions in their comment, it's a conversion to float.

Answer (score 1):

golfed version:

```
$ awk -F\; '{print (f=id==$2)?"Old":"New","person",$2,f?$2:$3;id=$2""}' file

New person 12201001201608502 114.384332
Old person 12201001201608502 12201001201608502
New person 12201001201608503 68.3642617
Old person 12201001201608503 12201001201608503
New person 12201001201608504 68.3642617
Old person 12201001201608504 12201001201608504
Old person 12201001201608504 12201001201608504
Old person 12201001201608504 12201001201608504
```

Comment: if you wanna actually golf it then try :::::::::::::::: :::::::::::: :::::: :::::::::: ::::::::: ::::::::::: :::::: `awk '{ print (_=___!=(___=____$__))?"New":"Old","person",$__,$(_+__) }' __=2 FS=';'`

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto my solution is 14 char shorter and still readable (though not for newbies)

Comment: @karkfa : since when is readability a requirement for code golfing ?

Comment: Yes, I meant it's shorter (and as a secondary benefit, readable).

Answer (score 1):

In awk, any input that looks like a number is considered to be of type "strnum" (or numeric-string if you prefer) so it can be treated as either a number or a string in your script depending on context. When you compare a "strnum" with another "strnum" (or with a "number") the type of comparison done is numeric. Internally all numbers in awk are floating point. You're trying to do a numeric comparison on a number that's too large to be represented accurately as a float on your system. Try this (note the `0` and `1` at the end of the numbers before the `+` signs):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print 12201001201608500+0}'
12201001201608500

$ awk 'BEGIN{print 12201001201608501+0}'
12201001201608500
```

to see such a failure. The solution as others have pointed out is to force a string comparison instead of a numeric comparison by forcing awk to consider your input as type "string" rather than "strnum", and you do that by performing a string operation, concatenating with `""`, on it:

```
if( ($2"") == id)
```

I'm doing it in the `$2 == id` comparison instead of the `id=$2` assignment because the first comparison happens before the first `id=$2` assignment (otherwise that first comparison given the earlier `id=0` will be "strnum" vs "number" which is a numeric comparison) and that's the line that actually cares about the difference.